# onscroll for div

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, dom-events

Does a div element not have an [`onscroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onscroll) event handler?
The behaviour on my page doesn't seem to indicate the div `onscroll` event handler is recognized.

```
<div id='bd' onscroll='alert("Scroll Called");'></div>
```

Also,
Do div scroll events roll up to window scroll events, as per DOM event bubbling ?

Answer (score 22):

Depending on which version of HTML you're using, you could use the `onwheel` event, instead.

The `onscroll` event works only if all the following are true:

1. The div has `overflow: auto`, `overflow: scroll`, `overflow-y: scroll`, etc.
2. The div currently has a visible scrollbar that can scroll.
3. The mouse movement actually causes the scrollbar to scroll.

So the `onscroll` event is not really suited for detecting general mouse wheel movement.

Please note that the `onwheel` event is new in HTML 5.  [According to w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onwheel.asp), it is pretty widely supported, though.

Comment: will onwheel catch an arrow press as well?

Comment: No. But you can set up a separate key listener for that.

Comment: It looks like the onwheel event is not supported on safari.

Answer (score 5):

I scratched my head on this one too, until I started learning more about DOCTYPE directives.  The onscroll attribute is not supported in most recent version of the HTML spec. It'll show as invalid syntax in Visual Studio.  It might work in many browsers, but it's still invalid code.

Instead, you canan event using Javascript or jQuery. I use an approach like this to synchronize scrolling on two separate div's:

```
$("#gridTableContainer").scroll(function() {
    HandlingScrollingStuff();
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't believe everything what Microsoft is telling about specs. They like do their own and they like to call them standards. And VS makes you feel like Word, being "right" and "valid" _according to MS_. Actually, only MS relies ultimately on the DOCTYPE whether doing quirks or not; all other browsers are simply displaying HTML. [Use MDN to learn HTML, CSS and JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.onscroll)! Never use w3schools, read why on [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com). MSDN is okay for IE, but don't rely on them. ps: onscroll event is HTML5 spec'd, without jQuery.

Comment: Ummm, yeah. That's what I was saying when I pointed out above that "it's still invalid" even if Visual Studio will show it as valid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes but the element needs to have a scrollbar. You can give it one with either `overflow: auto` (which gives you a scrollbar when the content is tall enough) or `overflow: scroll`. (These can be set specifically for x & y as well `overflow-y: scroll`...)

Although they don't bubble once the div has been scrolled to the bottom the window will start scrolling. (Basically if the div can scroll it will intercept the scroll event, but if it can't then it will go to the page)

Comment: Thanks. But, i have the overflow property set. I am scrolling the div, but not getting any alert. What may i be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I know it may not be exactly what you're looking for, but a lot of javascript frameworks can help you with this. It is not necessary for the div to have a scrollbar for you to hook to the scroll events.

Eg. Mootools has the `mousewheel` event. [Demo here](http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=MouseWheel). (It has scrollbars, but you can use Firebug to remove the scrollbars and try -- it still works).

I have used this myself on a [site](http://lundark.dk) I made a while back. If you scroll while holding your mouse over the images it prevents the default page scrolling and instead slides the image-bar.