# Using a closure with onscroll to keep pageYOffset’s last value

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change an example I found [here](http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/09/javascript-closure-explained-using-events), so that it would work with `onscroll` instead of `onclick`.
ultimately, the reason for using a closure is to avoid a global variable (to keep `pageYOffset`’s last value between function calls), but I'll start with this simple example:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myobj');

element.onscroll = (function() {
    // init the count to 0
    var count = 0;
    return function(e) {
        //count
        count++;
        if (count === 3) {
            // do something every third time
            alert("Third time's the charm!");
            //reset counter
            count = 0;
        }
    };
})();
```

Note: initially, I defined 'myobj' as a div, but then I defined like

```
<body id='myobj'>
```

with a bunch of paragraphs inside to have a scrollbar (for some reason, div didn't work).

using chrome's debugger, I can see it going through the code at page load time, but that's all.
nothing happens when I scroll. can someone explain me why?
thanks!

Comment: Where is this code on the page? Have you put it at the bottom of the body or inside a document onload handler?

Comment: inside a document. I'm struggling to put the html on this comment. sorry... this goes right before the </body>: <script type="text/javascript" src="windowscroll.js"></script>

Comment: What I'm getting at is, where your javascript lives makes a difference - if the script runs before the document has fully loaded, there's a good chance it won't work because the elements in question may not exist yet for attaching handlers to.

Comment: you're probably right. I just did a refresh on the page and, when hovering over element.onscroll, it indicates null.

Comment: Putting your javascript at the bottom of the body should help.

Comment: it is at the bottom (before the closing body tag). or do you mean after the </body>? is that allowed?

Comment: Before the closing body tag, but looking at your code, I realize now that because you're selecting the body as your element, technically it's probably not done loading yet. In that case you'll probably want to add it to a document.onload handler.

Comment: I believe it is "catching" the window. element has body#myobj in it. using the console to evaluate element.onscroll after calling the function, it returns the code for function(e) (i.e., what's supposed to be returned, right?)

Comment: I'll dig into it. thanks for your patience, kinakuta ;)

Answer (score 0):

there's a working solution, but in my case not The Solution. goes with CSS...
instead of referring to the body I've created a div:

```
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:  250px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-bottom: 120px;; 
}
```

and

```
var element = document.getElementById('div1');
element.onscroll = (function() {
    // init the count to 0
    var count = 0;
    return function(e) {
        //count
        count++;
        if (count === 3) {
            // do something every third time
            alert("Third scroll.");
            //reset counter
            count = 0;
        }
    };
})();
```

the script is working.
props 2 [Sildoreth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065237/sildoreth) for his [answer on "scroll for div"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950382/onscroll-for-div).
not exactly what I'm looking for, because I'm working with the whole window and I still haven't found a solution for this case. this is annoying because the whole window (div or not) has a scroll bar but it won't respond to this event.

@kinakuta: I thought about what you said (document.onload handler), but I couldn't come up with a solution there, mainly because that's supposed to invoke a function. right? seems to me this script is more of a declaration (despite of having an "implicit" call to a function).

---

seems like I've found - wouldn't say the definitive solution - but something closer to what I've been looking for.
I still have the div1 element but changed the css, so that the div uses the whole window (I've simplified the css the most I could):

```
#div1 {
  height: 3000px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

and, what really makes the difference, instead of getting the div1 element (as before), I'm getting the window itself:

```
var element = document.defaultView;
```

(nothing else has changed on the script.)

not sure if this is the most recommendable way, but it's working with the browser's scroll bar (not the div's, as before).