# Detect scroll event in AngularJS with "Find in page"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have implemented lazy-loading for the images in a web page.

I've bound the event 'wheel', checked the bounding rectangle and so on.

It works correctly when the user scrolls down the page.

It does NOT work if the user searches for text in the page ("Find in page...") and jumps to the bottom of the page with that.

Images are not loaded unless the scroll event (or "wheel" event) is triggered.

Is there any way to make this jump behave just like the page scrolled?

(I tried this in Chrome.)

Comment: What an interesting code you have. The scroll event is being fired when I'm searching for, e.g., `8` https://jsfiddle.net/twcnp60q/

Comment: @andale As I said, I'm using AngularJS, your example is not. I have a directive that uses link to detect the scroll event inside of my element. If I bind it with `$(elem).on('scroll', function (evt) {` it will not be detected. If I bind it with `$(elem).on('wheel', function (evt) {`, it will. If you insist I can post the code, but I don't see the point in this case.

Comment: I see. Well, if you want it to work on a custom element then add an overflow to that element. Read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950382/onscroll-for-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'scroll' event, 'wheel' is no good here.

Also notice that user can use mouse to drag scroll or page down, page up or arrows -- and all this wont trigger 'wheel' but will trigger 'scroll' events.

Comment: Can you have a look at my other comment and tell me what you think?

Comment: @ChatterOne wheel event can be handled on i.e. tr, td, etc. while scroll can be handled only on element which is screolled. So you might use wrong element - some child of actually scrolled element.

Comment: That was actually the case, I had a nested element for `md-content` that was the one needing the directive for scrolling. Once I put the directive in the right element, the `scroll` event started working.