# react - in onscroll method how to detect page has reached bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to handle the **onScroll** event in react to detect the page end and then fire rest call to get more details.

However, I am not able to figure out how to calulate if bottom has reached.

```
   componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchShows()
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
      }

    handleScroll = (e) => {
        console.log("handleScroll")

        const windowHeight = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
        const body = document.body;
        const html = document.documentElement;
        const docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight,  html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
        const windowBottom = windowHeight + window.pageYOffset;

        console.log(windowBottom)
        if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {
          console.log("bottom Reached")
        } else {

        }
}
```

Seems like Window or document object is not accessible inside method `handleScroll`

If I put any of the line at the begining of `handleScroll` then seems like none of the line get executed.

```
console.log("handleScroll")
console.log(document)
console.log(window)
console.log(e.target)
console.log("testing")
```

in Above scenario,  `handleScroll` is printed but nothing after that.

Comment: did you specify an `overflow` style in css? aka `overflowY: auto;` or something of the sort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onscroll for div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950382/onscroll-for-div)

Comment: I have modified the question, I don't think it's duplicate.

Comment: your code is working for me