# How to correctly change the size of a div with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to change the size of a div through javascript. Making it smaller works but I can't get it back to normal size after shrinking it.

Here's the code :

```js
 

   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body onscroll="myFunction()">

    <div class="row iconBar">
        <div class="col">
            <img class="icons" src="insta.png">
            <img class="icons" src="email.png">
            <img class="icons" src=tel.png>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row sticky-top titleBar" id="headerBar" onscroll="myFunction()">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="logo.jpg" id="logo" alt="logo.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- script resize when scrolling up/down -->
    <script>

        var divHeight = 0;
        var imgSize = 0;

        var header = document.getElementById("headerBar");
        var logo = document.getElementById("logo");

        window.onload = function () {
            divHeight = document.getElementById("headerBar").offsetHeight;
            imgSize = document.getElementById("logo").offsetWidth;
        };

        window.onscroll = function() {

            if (header.offsetTop > 50) {
               header.style.height = "20vh";
               logo.style.with = "12%";
            }
            else {
                header.style.height = "40vh";
               logo.style.width = "20%";
            }

        }
    </script>

    <div class="row infoBar">
        <div class="col-md-3 infoImgCol">
            <img src="haftbefehl.jpg" id="infoImg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 infoText">
            <p>
               Text
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row coursePlan" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Start</th>
                    <th scope="col">Until</th>
                    <th scope="col">Coach</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">19.08.2019</th>
                    <td>9:00</td>
                    <td>13:00</td>
                    <td>Diabolo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">19.08.2019</th>
                    <td>13:00</td>
                    <td>16:00</td>
                    <td>Fat Tony</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">21.08.2019</th>
                    <td>8:00</td>
                    <td>12:00</td>
                    <td>Larry the lobster</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">22.09.2019</th>
                    <td>13:00</td>
                    <td>15:30</td>
                    <td>Abo</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="row press">
        <div class="col">
            <p style="font-size: 3em; margin-top:5vh;">Press</p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 10vh;">
                Text
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p style="margin-left: 1vw; margin-top: auto;margin-bottom: auto;">Warung Yoga Gmbh ©</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>


</html>
```

CSS:

```
    .icons{
        width:2%;
        float:right;
        margin-right:1vw;
        margin-top:2vh;
        background-color: white;
    }

    .titleBar{
        background-color: white;
        text-align: center;
        position: sticky;
        top:0;
    }
    #logo{
        width: 20%;

    }
    .infoBar{

        margin-top: 5vh;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
        color: white;
    }
    .infoImgCol{
        text-align: center;
    }
    #infoImg{
        width: 60%;
    }
    .infoText{
        text-align: center justify;
        margin: auto;
    }   

    .coursePlan{
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top: 10vh;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .newsTitle{
        background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
        margin-top: 10vh;
        text-align: center;
        color:white;
    }

    .press{
        background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
        color:white;
        margin-top:5vh;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

I'm storing the default size in divHeight when the page is loaded.
Once I shrink my div, I want it to change back to normal once I reach the top of the page again.

Comment: Please include *all* of the relevant code to repro the issue. There is no scrolling on what's provided.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've now included the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `window.onscroll` event, instead of the `div onscroll`. `div onscroll` will only work under [specific conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950382/onscroll-for-div).

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    myFunction()
}
```

Also, you didn't specify the logo image size so it's hard to determine exactly what you're trying to do. Instead of setting specific width/height after scrolling, why not simply clear the `style` properties?

```
function myFunction() {
    if (header.offsetTop > 50) {
        header.style.height = "20vh";
        logo.style.width = "12%";
    }
    else {
        header.style = "";
        logo.style = "";
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/kAVzV0UGbB

Comment: Yes. One of the problems with the OP's code is that they try to assign the original offsetHeight (which is an integer number) to the style property.

Comment: Hmm strange, I copied the exact same code, your codesnippet does work the way I want it to (resizing to normal when scrolling back to the top). But somehow it doesn't work for my page.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of a div using `jQuery` (place this above your script which should be just above your closing body tag):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can change the css of content with:

```
$("#idofdiv").css("height", "whatever height you want");
```

I am not sure when you actually want to change the size of your div because your question is sort of unclear but hopefully this helps!

Comment: This sadly didn't work, it doesn't get back to normal size when scrolling to the top

Comment: That would be something to do with you function then most likely